# Tested Thoroughly, Still don't know why Computer Locks Up Randomly

Tags: memory, windows-8.1, freeze

I've had this problem and it's been an ongoing battle of diagnosis for months now. My computer will, at seemingly random times, simple freeze up. Mouse stops moving, CTRL-ALT-DLT doesn't do anything, nor does anything fix the problem besides a hard reset.

System Specs:
- Win8.1 Pro
- i7-3770k Non Overclocked
- EVGA GTX 760 2gb ACX
- Crucial Ballistix Sport 8GB
- Corsair CX500
- Samsung 840 Pro 120gb
- WD Caviar Black 1TB

I've RMA'd the motherboard and gone through two power supplies, memtested the memory, and 3dmarked the GPU, all with no issues. Yet the problem persists. Nothing is created in Event Viewer, there are no temp issues (max system temp is 40C, GPU 60C, CPU 55C) and no error messages ever explain the problem. I'm pretty sure all drivers are up to date, and I've reformatted and reinstalled windows twice already.

I'm stuck.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem?  Can you make it happen at will?

Comment: No, should've mentioned that. It will sometimes happen when gaming, but other times I can go a week with no lockup while playing games nonstop. Other times it will freeze when doing simple things like listening to music or even just browsing the internet.

Comment: Final thing to test software is to run new install of windows with only basic apps like office apps, internet, etc and see if problem stays;  No games, antivirus, special background apps, etc.

Comment: Really it sounds like faulty hardware.  Focus on CPU (swap known good?), RAM, MB, and drive with software (as opposed to user files).  I've ran dhrystone and whetstone tests that led me to a bad CPU, although you would need to run for extended periods of time.  Prime 95 ran fine though in my case.  Mem test should optimally be ran for extremely long times (a week is not too long) if your problem is intermittent like that.  Drive having a blip of error would be hard to track.

Comment: Have you updated the firmware on your SSD?